# to_hdf in python 3 causes MemoryError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, hdf5

I'm writing a piece of code for my thesis which collects a series of .csv files that represent temperature images. I want to make the use of these .csv files more efficient by storing them into a dataframe.

I have multiple videos of +10000 frames and each video should be stored in a separate dataframe. I made a code that works for lower numbers of files, however when running the code on a bunch of videos (lets say 10), it crashes after a couple of videos. It returns the MemoryError. I already tried gc.collect() functions and deleted the dataframe after using df.to_hdf to prevent python of keeping lists open in memory that have been created. My memory usage still keeps increasing until it completely fills up the RAM, and it crashes.

the relevant piece of the code is added here.

```
dfs={}
for l in range(k*number_of_csv,len(i)):
    df=pd.read_csv(i[l],sep=',',header=None)
    dfs['{:0>8}'.format(i[l])] = df
dfs=pd.concat(dfs)
dfs.to_hdf('experiment_data_series_'+str(k)+'.h5',key='raw',mode='w')
del dfs
gc.collect()
```

in short: it builds a dataframe from all the csv files and then stores them into the h5 file.

Can someone detect what is missing to prevent this from overconsuming memory?
I already inserted a chunking procedure, so that the number of .csv files that is stored in a single h5 is always <20000. (usually the h5 file has a size of 3-4GB)

I suspect that python allocates some memory for the storing operation, but doesn't liberate it afterwards or something.
I'd appreciate the help.

kind regards,
Cedric

Comment: Have you tried moving the `df.to_hdf()` statement inside the for-loop?  This way you could could make different HDF keys (nested or flat) for each `.csv` file.  Also consider converting any `np.float64` values to `np.float32` if your application allows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, i tried it with smaller files and noticed that there is actually no memory leak, it is just that dfs gets too large, consuming my memory. as soon as the code has saved it as hdf, the memory usage drops down to 30%, which is the baseline use of this pc. (time to construct the dataframe is greater than the time required to convert it to hdf). if i move the to-hdf inside of the for loop, can i then avoid having to make the dfs array at all? will it append and keep the index?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have stated that each video should be stored in a *separate* dataframe I don't think you need to concatenate them all into `dfs`.  Simply read in each `.csv` file and then write them to your `HDFStore` under its own key; imagine a `dict` of `DataFrame` objects.

Consider the following code:

```
# create an HDF5 file which will contain all your data;
# this statement automatically opens the h5 file for you
hdf = pd.HDFStore('experiment_data_series.h5')

for l in range(k*number_of_csv,len(i)):
    df = pd.read_csv(i[l], sep=',', header=None)

    # store this dataframe in the HDF5 file under some key
    hdf['raw_{}'.format(k)] = df

# when you are finished writing to the HDF5 file remember to close it
hdf.close()
```

later on you can open the file again and view some information

```
hdf = pd.HDFStore('experiment_data_series.h5', mode='r')
print(hdf.info())
print(hdf.keys())

# you can get one dataframe by its key
df = hdf.select('raw_0', auto_close=True)
```

I think this should work because you won't be having all of your data loaded in memory at once, i.e., you are using the disk instead.

Comment: this looks very promising, i'll try and adapt the code that i have, and see if this works. thanks a lot